# Why ethanol doesn't react with NaOH ,while methanol does?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

Why ethanol doesn't react with NaOH ,while methanol does?

Comment: Who says it doesn't? Who says it does?

Comment: my teacher said this, but I don't remember the reason

Comment: It would make it a better question if you gave more information in the form of where you obtained the information about the difference between methanol and ethanol from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methanol will react a little with NaOH because it is an acid slightly stronger than ethanol. Ethoxide ion is a stronger base than methoxyde because of the induced effect due to C2H5. So ethanol is a weaker acid.

Comment: Why is my answer downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that methanol, ethanol and water all have similar strucutres. They will have similar pKas. I know that the pKas will increase in the order water, methanol and ethanol. The pKa of ethanol is about 18.

I think an equilibrium will exist between either methanol (or ethanol) and sodium hydroxide. It will be

$$\ce{MeOH + OH- <=> MeO- + H2O}$$

So I think that sodium hydroxide will partly react with both methanol and ethanol. The ethanol will react slightly less as the slightly greater electron releasing nature of the ethyl group will make the ethoxide a stronger base than methoxide.